# Cell Referencing Formula

Tags: excel

Was using this formula *SheetName!CellAddress*

I need to import Data that is available on other 2 sheets namely (sheet2 and sheet3)  into sheet 1 in a way such that

the row values will be alternate i.e one value from sheet 2 and other value from sheet 3 respectively

Have tried like this 
=Sheet2!C2
=Sheet3!D2

when i dragged for other values i was get only values in the even cell like(c4,d4,c6,d6)
If i change the for formula to

=Sheet2!C1
=Sheet3!D1
i was get only values in the even cell like(c3,d3,c5,d5)

But what i need is continous cells in row( c1,d1,c2,d2,c3,d3...)

So what formula i need to use for getting this result

Comment: Are the final formulas supposed to be in one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not 100% clear on what the question is asking, so let me know if the below answer doesn't work for you.

It sounds like what you're looking for can be accomplished with `OFFSET` and clever use of `IF` statement.

Suppose your formulas will be in column `A`, starting in `A2`.  Then enter the following formula into `A2` (line split added for readability; remove it):

```
= IF(MOD(COUNTA(A$1:A1),2)=0, OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$1, COUNTA(A$1:A1) / 2, 0), 
    OFFSET(Sheet3!$D$1, COUNTA(A$1:A1) / 2, 0))
```

Then drag the formula down.

What it does:

- `MOD(COUNTA(A$1:A1),2)=0` - checks whether we're in odd row or even row.
- `COUNTA(A$1:A1)/ 2` - takes half of the number of non-empty cells immediately above the current cell.
- `OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$1, COUNTA(A$1:A1) / 2, 0)` - takes the cell which is `COUNTA(A$1:A1)/ 2` cells below `Sheet2!$C$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly basic method:

1. Enter the first two formulas as *Text* - you can either do this by formatting the cell number as text or preceding the formula by an apostrophe.
2. Select cells and fill down to get:

   ```
   =Sheet2!C2
   =Sheet3!D2 
   =Sheet2!C3
   =Sheet3!D3
   =Sheet2!C4
   =Sheet3!D4
   ...
   ```
3. Select the column and choose `Data|Text to Columns|Finish` to change text to values.

Comment: but i was getting after draging  =Sheet2!C8
=Sheet3!D8
=Sheet2!C9
=Sheet3!D9
=Sheet2!C10
=Sheet3!D10

Comment: Just to clarify you need to evaluate the formulas in the last step so they display as values. If you want to do this with data in rows, first format the number of the first two cells as *Text*, drag the fill handle and then choose Edit|Replace (Ctrl+H) Find:`=` Replace With:`=`.

Comment: No taht is not the problem for the above  code also it is giving the result in the same way